# Triggering onclick button with Python mechanize

Tags: python, onclick, mechanize

So,here's the problem:
I got a form that gives an info. The form has only one field and i can easily write inside anything using .select_form and .form functions of mechanize.

However the submit func.doesn't work as well as it should.

How can i click the onclick button using mechanize?
I know it's JS but it should be a proper way to do it also in Py.

This is the HTML code of the form:

```
<input type="text" name="P_COD" value="IT001990225863" class="textbox2" maxlength=14 size=20 onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Search" onclick="query()" class="pulsante">
```

I've tried also `br.click('Search')`, it correctly point to the button, but gives the following error: `ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'Search', kind 'clickable'`

this is the list of the forms:

```
<HiddenControl(P_CAP=BOV) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(P_COD_S=) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(P_COD=IT001990225863)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use something like Selenium, or else a headless browser, to run JavaScript on your pages. Mechanize does not have a JavaScript engine built-in.

Comment: Ok, i'll try using Selenium. I'll let you know.